# Find a sub-ring of M(2, $\mathbb{Q}$) which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I believe that for a subring to be isomorphic it needs to be a ring homomorphism but i'm not sure how to go about finding isomorphic rings, I'm not looking for a straight up answer I'm trying to understand how to go about the question.

Comment: Now a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3128813/29335 by the same user